# @PropertyMapping with list parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the next annotation with `@PropertyMapping`:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@ImportAutoConfiguration
@PropertyMapping("spring.test.testcontainers.datasource")
public @interface AutoConfigureDatasourceContainer {

    @PropertyMapping("containers")
    DatasourceContainer[] containers() default {};
}
```

And child annotation:

```
@Target({})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface DatasourceContainer {

    @PropertyMapping("port")
    int port() default 31335;

    @PropertyMapping("username")
    String username() default "";

    @PropertyMapping("password")
    String password() default "";

    @PropertyMapping("database")
    String database() default "";

    @PropertyMapping("type")
    DatasourceType type() default DatasourceType.MYSQL;
}
```

I expect that usages of this two annotations in next form:

```
@AutoConfigureDatasourceContainer(containers =
        {
                @DatasourceContainer(username = "username", password = "password", database = "users", type = DatasourceType.MYSQL)
    })
```

will produce next property:

```
spring.test.testcontainers.datasource.containers[0].port=31335
spring.test.testcontainers.datasource.containers[0].username=username
.....
```

and so on. But this is not so.

I didn't find any examples in documentation about situations like this.
What is wrong with my code?